# C: Adding two 32-bit unsigned integers from raw memory bytes

Tags: c, pointers, memory, type-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

In C, I have three memory areas that are several hundred bytes long. I want to take the `i`th pair of 32 bits of the two memory areas, add them as two unsigned 32-bit integers, and store the result in the respective 64 bits of the third memory area (because two 32-bit ADDs can produce a 33-bit result), without storing them in actual `uint32t`'s before addition happens, rather: directly reading them from memory, telling the compiler to treat them as `uint32t'`s, and also telling the compiler to add them up and store the result in the first 64 bits of the third memory area.

`n1->bits`, `n2->bits` and `R->bits` are the pointers to my three memory areas respectively. Originally their types are `uint8_t*`

I have made sure that the three memory areas' sizes are divisible by 32.

Note: `carry` is an actual variable of type `uint32_t`, and shouldn't be needing attention when answewring.

THE PROBLEM: For some reason the compiler does read them as two unsigned 32-bit integers, but **refuses to store their result in the first 64 bits of the Result** memory area, instead it overflows. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
*((uint64_t*)( ((uint32_t*)(R->bits)) + i)) = 
            *( ((uint32_t*)(n1->bits)) + i)
            +
            *( ((uint32_t*)(n2->bits)) + i)
            +
            carry;
            ;
```

Here is my current understanding of how this code should work. Correct me where I'm wrong please:

1. Get to the first address of the memory area using `R->bits`

2. Cast this pointer to a `(uint32t*)` so that when we do the pointer arithmetic `+i`, the compiler increments by units of 32 bits (thus, getting us to the i-th unsigned 32-bit integer). Without this cast, the pointer arithmetic `+i` would have been translated to `+ (i * 8) bits` instead of `+ (i * 32) bits` by the compiler, since `R->bits` is originally a `uint8_t*` .
*
3. *Now that we've told the compiler to treat R->bits as a pointer to a `uint32t`, do the actual pointer arithmetic `+i` in order to get to the i-th 32-bit integer in the large memory areas.

4a. In the case of the two ADD operands, dereference the pointer you got to via the casts and the pointer arithmetic to read the actual values of the supposed unsigned 32-bit integers there.

*(This step 4b is where I think my understanding is wrong)*
4b. In the case of the Result buffer, don't dereference yet. First, cast the pointer to the i-th 32-bit region to a `uint64_t*` **and then** dereference it and use it as the result of built-in addition, in order to tell the compiler to store the result of this built-in addition in the first 64 bits of the i-th 32-bit region because, again, an ADD on two 32-bit operands can produce a 33-bit result.

Except, it doesn't do it.

I tried it with both operand memory areas filled with hundreds of 1s, and what it did was, it took the first 32 ones, added them together, which should have produced:
**00000001** **11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110**

And since my machine is little-endian, the memory layout of the result should have been:
**11111110  11111111 11111111 11111111 00000001**

**EXCEPT,** when I looked at the memory of the result buffer, it was missing that extra 33rd **1** in the 5th byte. The 5th byte was all zeroes. Which means it refused to listen to me when I told it to treat the memory location it go to in the result buffer **as a 64-bit zone** via that cast to a `uint64_t*` .

Can someone explain why? Given my code and my current understanding of how it should to be working?

Comment: "I have made sure that the three memory areas' sizes are divisible by 32." is good, but not sufficient.  It is also important  that the base address of memory areas `n1, n2, R` meets the alignment requirements of `uint32_t, uint32_t, uint64_t`.  To well answer this part of the problem, post code showing the origin of `n1, n2, R`.

Comment: `*( ((uint32_t*)(n2->bits)) + i)` can be written as  `((uint32_t*)(n2->bits))[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is not related to the pointer arithmetic (although there is likely undefined behavior involved), but to the types in use.

What you have above is equivalent to:

```
uint64_t result;
uint32_t n1, n2, carry;
// set n1, n2, and carry to some values
result = n1 + n2 + carry;
```

When you add two values with type `uint32_t` together, the result has type `uint32_t`.  So if the result oveflows it will simply wrap around, i.e. it will "trim" all but the low 32 bits.

You need to cast one of the arguments to type `uint64_t` so that the addition is done with that type, i.e.:

```
result = (uint64_t)n1 + n2 + carry;
```

Or, going back to your code:

```
*((uint64_t*)( ((uint32_t*)(R->bits)) + i)) = 
            (uint64_t)*( ((uint32_t*)(n1->bits)) + i)
            +
            *( ((uint32_t*)(n2->bits)) + i)
            +
            carry;
            ;
```

Also, you have a strict aliasing violation if the arrays in question have type `uint8_t`, and the 64 bit values stored in `R->bits` are likely overlapping each other.

A fully compliant version of what you want would look like this:

```
uint64_t result;
uint32_t v1, v2;

memcpy(&v1, n1->bits + sizeof(v1) * i, sizeof(v1));
memcpy(&v2, n2->bits + sizeof(v2) * i, sizeof(v2));

result = (uint64_t)v1 + v2 + carry;

memcpy(R->bits + sizeof(result) * i, &result, sizeof(result));
```

Comment: I found my mistake as soon as you posted the answer haha, and we both reached the same conclusion. As for the aliasing violation, nothing is overlapping each other because I did a number of 32bit+32bit ADDs over the same two memory areas, storing each result in the respective Result buffer zone. The reason I don't have to worry about overlapping here is that this is part of an implementation of BigNum addition working in base 2^32, so adding separate 32-bit limbs. I have logic that processes the leftover 33rd bit which is the only bit residing in the latter part of the 64 bit zones. It works.

Comment: @KevinStefanov `(uint32_t*)(R->bits)) + i)` for consecutive values of `i` are 4 bytes apart, so if you write a 64 bit value there they will in fact overlap.  The aliasing violation happens because you're accessing an array of `uint8_t` as values of type `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.  "It works" is not by any means guaranteed.

Comment: Well there might be a strict aliasing violation; it depends on how the implementation maps the `uint8_t` type. If it is mapped to an extended unsigned integer type there would be a strict aliasing violation. If it is mapped to `unsigned char` there would not be a strict aliasing violation. But a portable program should not assume that.

Comment: @IanAbbott Only if you're going *to* that type from another.  Going *from* that type to another is still a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @IanAbbott And given OPs use case, it seems the memory buffers should have just been declared the appropriate type to begin with.

Comment: @dbush It depends if the object already has an effective type or not.

Comment: dbush, Detail "You need to cast one of the arguments to type uint64_t so that the addition is done with that type" --> 1 of the 2 leading arguments needs the cast.  Casting `carry` as in `n1 + n2 + (uint64_t) carry` is too late.

Comment: @0___________ Looks like I forget some parameters.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Pointer punning violates strict aliasing rules. You need to use `memcpy` or `char` access.

```
void add3264(void *src1, void *src2, void *dest)
{
    uint32_t a,b;
    uint64_t result;

    memcpy(&a, src1, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(&b, src1, sizeof(b));
    result = (uint64_t)a + b;
    memcpy(dest, &result, sizeof(result));
}
```

or

```
uint32_t get32(void *ptr)
{
    unsigned char *ucptr = ptr;
    return ucptr[0] + (uint32_t)ucptr[1] << 8 + (uint32_t)ucptr[2] << 16 + (uint32_t)ucptr[3] << 24;
}

void write64(void *ptr, uint64_t val)
{
    unsigned char *uc = ptr;
    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(val); index++)
    {
        *uc++ = val;
        val >>= 8;
    }
}

void add3264_1(void *src1, void *src2, void *dest)
{
    uint32_t a,b;
    uint64_t result;

    a = get32(src1);
    b = get32(src2);;
    result = (uint64_t)a + b;
    write64(dest, result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found where the mistake is: After dereferencing the two memory locations of the two ADD operands to get the actual unsigned integers' values, additionally cast them to (uint64_t). Also change `carry`'s type to also be uint64_t. Now the entire addition is done using only uint64_t's and works as intended.

Comment: You `*(uintxx_t *)` is bad as it may invoke undefined behaviour. Never do this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).